# Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have entity and rest controller, when I make a request to my controller it throws this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/createCharacter")
public Character createCharacters(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, @RequestParam("mapId") long mapId) {
    return createCharactersService.createCharacters(userId, mapId);
}
```

My entity has int type id:

```
  @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried to change Integer to Long or String it helped to fix my problem but in this case my Spring Data Rest for user entity doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you declare an Id as a String, is it a uuid? Usually Ids are of type Long in the entity, especially when the the relative id field in database is Big Integer.

Comment: Ye, it is UUID. But now i replaced it with primitive numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Id is a uuid you must keep it as a string in the entity.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;
```

Therefore you are bound to use it as a String in Service and in Controller.

```
@GetMapping("/createCharacter")
public Character createCharacters(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, @RequestParam("mapId") long mapId) {
    return createCharactersService.createCharacters(userId, mapId);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who find this issue based on the error:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Type@abdc80fc] did not match expected type [Type (n/a)]
```

You might be using JPA like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface OtherRepository extends JpaRepository<Other, Long> {
    List<Other> findAllByType(final Type type);
```

In that case, please make use of the id of Type (thus: `findAllByTypeId`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JPA with @Query for example :

```
 @Query("SELECT r FROM Employee r WHERE r.empId = ?1)
 Employee getMyEmployee(long id);
```

OR

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Employee r WHERE r.empId = :id)
Employee getMyEmployee(@Param("id") long id);
```

Make sure the passing parameter is **long** value and *empId* also a **long** value. If you execute the method
`classObj.getMyEmployee(someIntVariable)`
by passing **int** value it could cause the above error.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I have used DTOs so

**Previously** my @query was like this

```
@query("SELECT ... WHERE ucs.district = ?1")
```

**Then** I changed @query like this

```
@query("SELECT ... WHERE ucs.district.id = ?1")
```